# Custom Domains in web authentication flow

Tags: oauth2, authentication, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, custom-domain

I'm running into authentication issues with users who are attempting to sign into Salesforce on our product using a custom domain (Oauth user-agent flow).  From the Salesforce web signin page, the user taps "Use Custom Domain".  They enter the custom domain provided by their admin, and proceed to log in via whatever flow has been set up for their org (Okta, another Salesforce login page, etc).

The problem arises when the user finishes this auth flow.  Rather than routing to the inputted redirect URI including access code, etc., the user is just routed to their Salesforce homepage, so authentication cannot be completed.

When logging in with a custom domain, the user should be diverted to a separate flow, and then redirected to the provided redirect URI, right?  We're using the standard redirect URI, `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success`  Why would the user get routed to their Salesforce homepage rather instead?